# leaflet slow drag problem in firefox and safari

Tags: reactjs, firefox, safari, leaflet, react-leaflet

The problem i'm facing is i have some icons that i should show on my map that the user can interact with them, they were `svg` files and i read somewhere that the problem is caused cause of `svgs` and how `firefox` has a problem in rendering them, so i created those icons with css and i'm still facing this issue, is there any workarounds about this?
And the way i display map is like this:

```
                    <LeafletMap
                        center={[this.state.mapLat, this.state.mapLng,]}
                        zoom={17}
                        maxZoom={20}
                        attributionControl={true}
                        zoomControl={false}
                        doubleClickZoom={true}
                        scrollWheelZoom={true}
                        dragging={true}
                        animate={true}
                        easeLinearity={0.35}
                    >
                        <TileLayer
                            url='http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
                        />
                        {markers.map(item =>
                            <Marker position={[item.lat, item.lng]} className="heyyya" icon={L.divIcon({
                                className: 'marker',
                                html: `
                                <div class="map-icon" id=${item.id}>
                                    <div class="circle">
                                        <div class="inner-circle">${item.free_count}</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                            `,
                                iconSize: [40, 40],
                                iconAnchor: [24, 24]
                            })} title={item.free_count} key={item.id} id={item.id} onClick={goToPlace}>

                            </Marker>
                            

                        )}


                    </LeafletMap >
```